# Dropbox API Chooser with JS from staging server : Origin does not match any app domain

Tags: dropbox-api

Dropbox API Chooser with JS from staging server : Origin does not match any app domain, popup message i got. The url of stazing  server is "https". How to configure https://*.com. in the drop box drop-ins.

Comment: my localserver and network server is sample.com and my production server url is sample.net. Ihave a problem production server, I think my production server domain url is ended with .net. and any problem with https. Can i give these url mentioned in OAuth Redirect Url in drop-ins of dropbox. My Product have different accounts . can i use same app key to all accounts. Please respond as early as possible

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a specific hostname (e.g. www.example.com). Wildcards are not supported.

Comment: The host name is like https://www.sample.com of . How to configure https:// in drop-ins of dropbox. The domain url not supported https://. How to solve this.

Comment: If you put in sample.com, then it will work. The scheme (http or https) doesn't matter.

Comment: If the issue is that your app is working from your production domain but not your staging domain, just make sure to add your staging domain in the App Console too (same place you added your production domain).

Comment: HI smarx, my localserver and network server is http://www.sample.com and my production server url is https://www.sample.net. Ihave a problem production server, I think my production server domain url is ended with .net. and any problem with https. Can i give these url mentioned in OAuth Redirect Url in drop-ins of dropbox. My Product have different accounts . can i use same app key to all accounts. Please respond as early as possible.

Comment: I'm having trouble keeping track of the problem. Is there a specific error you're trying to fix?